# Why do browserSync link to WAMP homepage (when there is no internet) instead of the virtualhost homepage

Tags: wordpress, apache, npm, dns, wampserver

I am using browsersync and a virtualhost (set up with WAMP) for wordpress theme development.

Here is the  problem - assume my virtualhost name is "mydomain.dev" and my internet connection is ON. On gulping, browserSync automatically launches chrome, It goes to "mydomain.dev" and everything work just fine, no hassles.

However, when there is no internet connection, browsersync launches chrome but it doesn't go to "mydomain.dev". Instead, it shows "localhost:81" and keep loading until it gives an error.

When I changed the proxy in my gulp.js file to 127.0.0.1, browsersync launches chrome with "localhost" but sends me to WAMP homepage. I checked my host file in windows > system32.....and its all fine.

Here is my virtlahost configuration file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mydomain.dev
     ServerAlias mydomain.dev
     DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/mydomain
     ErrorLog "logs/mydomain.log"
     CustomLog "logs/mydomain-access.log" common
     <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/mydomain">
         AllowOverride all
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

here is my windows32 > drivers > etc > host file

```
#local for virtual hosts
127.0.0.1   mydomain.dev
```

and here is the browserSync intialization section in the gulpfile

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
var files = [
    main + '**/*.css', main + '**/*.scss',
    js + '**/*.js',
    root + '**/*.php'
];

browserSync.init(files, {
   open: 'external',
   proxy: 'mydomain.dev',
   port: 80,,
});
```

I have been googling for solutions for two days but no success. I have also checked browserSync documentation but no success. I am thinking there is something I could be getting wrong. (Maybe browsersync requires internet to use virtualhosts).

However, I have tried setting browsersync "offline" to true and I have also restarted DNS on WAMP. I have tried to reload windows cache using `*net stop "DNS client"` and `*net start "DNS client"`

I have also tried moving my project folder out of the Wamp folder and creating another virtual host to link to this folder but it still gives the same issue.

At a point, I thought my virtual host configuration could be faulty so I  used the "create virtualhost" option on WAMP's homepage to set up another virtualhost but it's all the same. I also set browsersync *open* to "local" but its all the same.

At this point, I can say Apache does not need internet to use virtual host because everything turns out fine if I type the virtualhost name in the address bar but this is not in sync with browserSync so I need to make browserSync open it itself without internet connection.

I am wondering what could be wrong. I really need to be able to develop my theme offline as I only have the opportunity to develop with internet once in a while.

Please, is there anyway I can get around this issue or is this the way browserSync has been configured to work?

Any help or explanation will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "when there is no internet" Remember, if you dont have internet, then likely as not the network stack is also not loaded and therefore TCP wont be there

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly for taking the time to respond. I'm sorry if this question sounds confusing but I'm new to the virtualhost & the TCP/IP thing. What I initially thought was, since a virtualhost has been configured and registered then browsersync is supposed to call the virtualhost name (like typing it directly into the address bar). Now, since things didn't work out the way I thought, does that mean browsersync needs the "network stack" (through a router or something) in order to work with virtual host (of which the absence of a router will make it impossible to call the domain name easily)?